# Закрыть ли запятую после "точнее" или после оборота с "точнее"?

Tags: пунктуация

> И даже церковь в том городе есть, точнее чёрный грот – катакомбы?

Ну как грот может уточнять церковь? Плакайу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**И даже церковь в том городе есть, точнее чёрный грот, – катакомбы?**

1) **КАТАКОМБЫ**, [итал. catacomba] 1. Обширные подземелья искусственного или естественного происхождения, состоящие из галерей, коридоров и небольших помещений (**в древнем Риме и других городах Римской империи служили первым христианам убежищем от гонений, местом богослужений и погребений**).

2) Массонский грот

[http://www.4turista.ru/content/poteshnyi-grot-ili-masonskii-khramУсадьба](http://www.4turista.ru/content/poteshnyi-grot-ili-masonskii-khram%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0) Горенки является самой большой по территории усадьбой Московской области ...самым интересным сооружением на её территории является **так называемый грот.** Это сооружение, в общем-то, полуподземное, сложенное из необработанных плит доломита и известняка. При внимательном взгляде приходит на ум, что такое сооружение имело не развлекательное, а скорее **культовое** назначение.

Ещё одним требованием было то, что пол в масонских храмах выкладывался плиткой или камнями (белыми и **чёрными**) в шахматном порядке

Answer (score 0):

Запятыми делу не поможешь. Надо понять мысль автора. Может так:

**И даже церковь в том городе есть, но не здание, а чёрный грот и катакомбы.**

Впрочем, надо еще посмотреть, совместимы ли грот и катакомбы.

> Грот — неглубокая горизонтальная пещера со сводчатым потолком и широким входом, (может быть искусственный грот, имитирующий естественную пещеру)
>
> Катакомбы Рима (итал. Catacombe di Roma) — сеть античных катакомб, использовавшихся как места погребений. Эти катакомбы представляют собой систему подземных ходов из туфа, зачастую образующих лабиринты.

Как сочетаются церковь, грот и катакомбы? Церковь в гроте и далее - катакомбы (места погребений)?

Comment: Это пересказ фрески. *Но вот действие переносится в стольный град – много башен, они разные и богато украшены... Рим? И даже церковь в том городе есть, точнее чёрный грот, – катакомбы? В нём горит светильник – служба идёт? И встречаются там человек из монастыря...* Посмотри, пожалуйста, "совместимы ли грот и катакомбы" - это меняет знаки.